# python + postgresql: how to generate random dataset 1 million rows by 1000 columns

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to test some ML model on datasets. But I have a requirement to test it on postgresql data.

I want to generate some mock data of 1000 columns (any types is fine) and 1 million rows.

How can I create such a table in postgresql.

Comment: [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/)?

Comment: Its limited to 1000 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
create table foo as select random() as col1, random() as col2,..., random() as col1000
from generate_series(1,1e6)
```

Fill in the ellipsis with the rest of the columns you want. You can get integers with `floor(random()*1000+1)::int as xyzsomething` and strings with `md5(random()::text) as t_876`, timestamp with for example `now() - interval '1 year' * random() as ts_356`.

If you ant some NULL scattered in the values randomly, then you need to write CASE statements, and that gets pretty verbose to have a thousand of them.

Comment: can i have bit mix of text, int, timestamp, float,